# Number of distinct group representations in a sample

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be $N$ members distributed in $k$ groups of sizes $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}$. Now, a sample $S$ of $d$ members is selected from this set of $N$ members. Let $c$ denote the number of distinct groups, whose representations are included in $S$. In how many ways $d$ members can be selected out of $N$, if one specifies the value of $c$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You could compute this recursively by considering cases for the number of elements selected from the first group.

Comment: I tried as follows: the first selection can be done in $N$ ways, the second selection in a different group can be done in $N/k$ ways (using the theorem of total probability), and so on the $c$ selection from $c$ different groups can be done in $N^{c}/\{ k^{c-1} (k-1)^{c-2}..(k-c+2)\}$ ways. Now the selection of $d-c$ members, constrained on the fact that they should fall in the $c$ groups selected earlier, can be done in $\{ ^{n_{1}+\ldots+n_{c}}C_{d-c}+\ldots+^{n_{k-c+1}+\ldots+n_{k}}C_{d-c}\}/^{k}C_{c}$ ways. Does this make any sense? Even if it does, is there a better way to represent this?